# Installed PHP and MySQL driver, but does not show in phpinfo() on Ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed PHP 7.2 on my Ubuntu box as well as various other PHP related packages, including `php7.2-mysql`.  I have also checked in `/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini` and ensured the following lines are uncommented as extensions:

```
extension=mysqli
extension=pdo_mysql
extension=pdo.so
```

However, despite all of that when showing `phpinfo()` in a browser, no MySQL drivers are listed under PDO and my Laravel application states that it cannot find the driver.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?  It must be something simple.

Comment: Did you restart your Apache? Also, `extension=mysqli` do extensions work without the `.so`?

Comment: did you try it after `apache` restart?

Comment: Yes tried after apache restart.  Sam result whether the .so is there or not.

Comment: Have you confirmed that `/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini` is the actual `.ini` file being used by PHP?

Comment: Yes, phpinfo() shows the ini file is being used.